# Info of website in database Symfony2,Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I`m looking for tips on how to make the information of website(title,description) stored in the database. As a CMS, you can edit the name of the page in the admin panel. Overall, I am looking for the best method to do something like that.

Second question:
If I have received from database result, how to refer to a specific value in the controller (loop like a twig?)

example:

Table General:

id --- name - price

1 aaaa 12

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
     ->getRepository('MySiteBundle:General');
    $products = $repository->findAll();
```

How to get the value of 12?

Answer (score 0):

First: The best way might be to create an entity (I name it `Application_Settings`) and create a form in admin page to be able to update that settings
Second: If you defined the entity properly you would have **get** and **set** in your entity; therefore you can easily try this in your controller:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MySiteBundle:General');
$products = $repository->findAll();
foreach($products as $p)
{
    //... Do your logic
    $p->getPrice();
}
```

Or if you pass `$products` to a twig file you can try

```
{% for p in products %}
    <span>Price: </span><span>{{ p.getPrice }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```